# Implement a bash script on a group of files in increments

Tags: linux, bash

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I'm just starting out and I'm kind of lost.  I have a group of about 3 thousand files that I want to run a command on.  Unfortunately, the program that the command is from (morphadorner) will only run on 8 files at a time.  The files are numbered consecutively.  How do I make the program iterate on every 8th file so that it processes all the files in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Say your files were called `file01`, `file02`...`file64`, you could then use `GNU Parallel` to process them like this:

```
parallel -j 1 -n 8 echo {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} ::: file*
```

And the output would be this:

```
file001 file002 file003 file004 file005 file006 file007 file008
file009 file010 file011 file012 file013 file014 file015 file016
file017 file018 file019 file020 file021 file022 file023 file024
file025 file026 file027 file028 file029 file030 file031 file032
file033 file034 file035 file036 file037 file038 file039 file040
file041 file042 file043 file044 file045 file046 file047 file048
file049 file050 file051 file052 file053 file054 file055 file056
file057 file058 file059 file060 file061 file062 file063 file064
```

Of course, I am only echoing the parameters, you would presumably call `morphadorner`.

The `-j 1` says to only run one `morphadorner` at a time - you may want to omit this and allow say 8 `morphadorners` to run at a time if you have 8 CPU cores.

The `-n 8` says to *consume* 8 arguments/files at time.

The `{1}` is a placeholder for the first argument, and the `{2}` is a placeholder for the second argument etc.

The `:::` is a separator that tells `GNU Parallel` that the arguments are about to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code:

```
    files=(*)
    count=${#files[@]}
    limit=8
    echo "Processing $count files: ${files[@]}"

    while [ $count -gt 0 ] ; do
            count=$((count-8))
            [ $count -lt 0 ] && limit=$((limit+count)) && count=0
            part=("${files[@]:$count:$limit}")
            echo $count-$((count+limit)): "${part[@]}"
    done
```